# Firebird / Entity Framework foreign key names

Tags: entity-framework, firebird

Using the Firebird .NET Provider and Entity Framework (code first), foreign key names seem to be of this convention:

FK_MyNetClassName1_MyNetClassName2

This makes it very easy to go over Firebird's 30 character limit.  Is there a way to control the foreign key names?  (Could they be based on my much shorter table names instead of class name?  Then they would be uppercase as well!)

Comment: And you're generating DDL from the CF model?

Comment: Yep!  This happens when I let EF create a new database.  An exception is thrown that lists the add constraint DDL and it says "Unsuccessful metadata update. Name longer than database column size".  My table/column names make it in ok, so I know it's seeing my entity type configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it directly. The name creation is hardcoded (currently) in provider. But you can let code generate the script and change it there to whatever you want.

Comment: What do you think of changing the provider to use table name?  Normally the convention is to name the foreign key FK_TABLE1_TABLE2.  Just a thought.

Comment: I mean changing the generated script.

Comment: "But you can let code generate the script and change it there to whatever you want." - can you support this text with some simple sample, please?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.